# How to simplify standard validation code with Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How can I simplify this standard code template with Java 8 lambdas ?

```
List<String> errors = ArrayList<String>();
String val = obj.getValue();
if ( StringUtils.isNotEmpty(val) ) {
    if ( !val.matches("regex") ) {
        errors.add("error message");
    }
    // more conditions ...
}
```

Comment: You could write `new ArrayList<>();`. Other than that, nothing comes to mind.

Comment: There's no way Lambdas would help here. A proper validation framework on the other hand...

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what this code is supposed to do generally..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet does not provide enough information to suggest a simplification. If we suppose, there are a lot of these pairs of patterns and error messages, simplifications are possible if you prepare a `Map` for these pairs, e.g.

```
Map<String,String> regex2message=new HashMap<>();
regex2message.put("regex1", "error message1");
regex2message.put("regex2", "error message2");
regex2message.put("regex3", "error message3");
regex2message.put("regex4", "error message4");
regex2message.put("regex5", "error message5");
```

once you have prepared this map, you can use it like

```
List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
String val = obj.getValue();
if( val!=null && !val.isEmpty() ) {
regex2message.forEach((regex,message)->{ if(!val.matches(regex)) errors.add(message); });
```

or using the `Stream` API:

```
List<String> errors = regex2message.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e->val.matches(e.getKey())? null: Stream.of(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Having such a map also offers deeper preparation for a more efficient execution of the actual match operation, i.e. if we perform the compilation of the regex `String`s into `Pattern` instances as preparation step:

```
Map<Pattern,String> pattern2message=regex2message.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->Pattern.compile(e.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
```

we can use this map later on this way:

```
List<String> errors = pattern2message.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e->e.getKey().matcher(val).matches()? null: Stream.of(e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```